# subgroups with cycles

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let Sym(n) denote the symmetric group on  n  letters
and let   H  be a subgroup of Sym(n) .
Suppose that H  contains a  k  cycle  for each value of  k  from 2  through  n .
This should be enough to conclude that H = Sym(n) .

Is there a direct proof of this (without appealing to a list of maximal subgroups)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the symmetric group is generated by any cycle of size $2$ and any cycle of size $n$.

Comment: @lisyarus You are mistaken! For example $(1,3)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$ do not generate $S_4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of an $n$-cycle shows that $H$ is transitive. Then the existence of an $(n-1)$-cycle shows that it is $2$-transitive. .... Prove by induction on $r$ that the existence of the $(n-r)$-cycle implies that $H$ is $(r+1)$-transitive.